# Rand gerando números iguais

Tags: c, random

Eu tenho que fazer um programa que gera números aleatórios pra x1 e x2 e realizar a operação F = x1*x1 + x2*x2; mas eu vou repetir isso 10 vezes e vou guardar o menor valor de F; depois, vou repetir 100 vezes e vou guardar o menor valor de F; e assim por diante;
A ideia é que o programa deve ter uma tendência de mostrar valores cada vez menores por causa da estatística
Porém, meu programa tá meio zoado, ele não tá mostrando valores cada vez menores, na real tá mostrando um monte de valor repetido
Onde eu to errando?

https://pastebin.com/zCx0EAtb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void FuncaoMenorValor(int z, int N, float* menoresF){ // z repersenta o tanto de vezes que a iteração do for vai rodar, N representa a posição do vetor menoresF que vai guardar o menor valor encontrado de F na iteração, e menoresF é o vetor que guarda os menores valores encontrados de F, de forma geral
float x1, x2, F = 0, menorF = 10;
int a, b, k, i;
    for(i = 0; i < z; i++){
        a = 1 + rand()%10; // dessa linha até a linha 24, é um algoritmo para gerar um numero no intervalo [-1,1]
        b = 1 + rand()%10;
        k = rand()%1;
        if(k == 0){
            x1 = (float) a/100;
        }
        if(k == 1){
            x1 = (float) -1*a/100;
        }
        k = rand()%1;
        if(k == 0){
            x2 = (float) b/100;
        }
        if(k == 1){
            x2 = (float) -1*b/100;
        }
        F = x1*x1+x2*x2;
        if(F < menorF){
            menorF = F;
        }
        if(i == (z-1)){ // quando o programa chega na ultima iteração, ele deve guardar o valor do menorF encontrado
            menoresF[N] = menorF;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

srand(time((NULL))); // seeda o rand

float menoresF[11];
int j;

FuncaoMenorValor(10, 0, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(20, 1, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(100, 2, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(200, 3, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(500, 4, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(1000, 5, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(2000, 6, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(10000, 7, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(20000, 8, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(50000, 9, menoresF);
FuncaoMenorValor(100000, 10, menoresF);

for(j = 0; j < 11; j++){ // printa todos os valores do vetor menoresF
        printf("\n%f", menoresF[j]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poste seu código aqui, melhor do que em repositórios externos. Para deixar ele com estilo de código, só começar cada linha com 4 espaços. Ou apertar `ctrl+k` no código aqui colado

Comment: Que tal mudar os `rand() % 1` por `rand() % 2`?